# Google App engine 404 on app spot (deploys locally)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am creating my first application using the google app engine launcher using python 2.7 and I am not able to deploy my application. Here are the steps I have take:

1. Created the app on the google developers console.
2. app.yaml has the name of the application and configs are correct.
3. Tested the application locally and it launches.
4. Get redirected to google after clicking deploy and I sign in to access the app and get redirected to:
   http://localhost:8080/?code=4/y8crEPdA5yunLMKIebPmjtojnhXKY4BWXhyzJDnkay8#
5. Go http://helloep-1100.appspot.com/ and I get a 404 error.

**helloworld_api.py**

```
 import endpoints
    from protorpc import messages
    from protorpc import message_types
    from protorpc import remote

    REQUEST_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        name=messages.StringField(1),
    )


    package = 'Hello'


    class Hello(messages.Message):
        """String that stores a message."""
        greeting = messages.StringField(1)


    @endpoints.api(name='helloworldendpoints', version='v1')
    class HelloWorldApi(remote.Service):
        """Helloworld API v1."""

        @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, Hello,
          path = "sayHello", http_method='GET', name = "sayHello")
        def say_hello(self, request):
          return Hello(greeting="Hello World")

        @endpoints.method(REQUEST_CONTAINER, Hello,
          path = "sayHelloByName", http_method='GET', name = "sayHelloByName")
        def say_hello_by_name(self, request):
          greet = "Hello {}".format(request.name)
          return Hello(greeting=greet)


    APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([HelloWorldApi])
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: helloep-1100
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1


handlers:


- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index\.html
  secure: always


- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld_api.APPLICATION
  secure: always


libraries:


- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was having was that I was attempting to deploy my application within a Vagrant machine. I launched my application from a different directory and was able to deploy successfully.